# CORS request did not succeed, webpack socket.io client

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, socket.io

I m using webpack with `socket.io-client(localhost:9000)` on mi client side, and i trying to connect to the server side `socket.io(localhost:3001)` server

///server side

```
const app = require("express")();

const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {


 // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});

var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');  

app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('public', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

const io = require('socket.io')(http,{
  allowUpgrades: true,
  transports: [ 'polling', 'websocket' ],
  pingTimeout: 9000,
  pingInterval: 3000,
  cookie: 'mycookie',
  httpCompression: true,
  log: false,
  agent: false,
  origins: '*:*',

});

//io.set({ origins: 'localhost:9000'});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});    

http.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log(`listening on ${3001}`);
});
```

And my client side looks like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../styles/style.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;

import io from 'socket.io-client';

var socket = io('https://localhost:3001');
//{transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']}

    socket.on('connect', () => {
 // Get a list of all files, previously delete existing
        // elements to avoid duplicates
        console.log(socket.connected); 
        socket.on('file', (files) => {
         console.log('Connected')

         })
   })
```

Alway give me: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MtbNn1m. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

Comment: Can you try setting the CORS-directive for socket.io via `io.set('origins','*:*')` and check if this changes something?

Comment: @nasskalte.juni Yes i already do that, and same results

Comment: for the record, you use cors library which sets headers and then you add your headers on top of it a line later. Remove one of the implementations.